# unable to use virtualenvwrapper on Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I tried `$ pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper` and it says that virtualenvwrapper is already there in python 3.6

I then tried

```
echo "# Virtual Environment Wrapper"
echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It says "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.shsource: No such file or directory"!

I tried to uninstall virtualenvwrapper and it says:

Cannot uninstall requirement virtualenvwrapper, not installed

My system cant seem to make a decision. It says virtualenvwrapper is installed and then says its not installed. Please help.

I would also like to add the fact that, I cant install any package without sudo command beacuse terminal says cache is disabled.

Answer (score 6):

In terminal type:
`which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
In my case showed me:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Now go to that location copy and place `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in :
  `/usr/local/bin/`